# in metaworks, boolean property value is not available in the EJS

Tags: ejs

My model is like as follows:

```
public class ParameterValue implements ContextAware{

String variableName;
    public String getVariableName() {
        return variableName;
    }
    public void setVariableName(String variableName) {
        this.variableName = variableName;
    }

String direction;
    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }
    public void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }


String argument;
    public String getArgument() {
        return argument;
    }
    public void setArgument(String argument) {
        this.argument = argument;
    }

boolean isMultipleInput;
    public boolean isMultipleInput() {
        return isMultipleInput;
    }
    public void setMultipleInput(boolean isMultipleInput) {
        this.isMultipleInput = isMultipleInput;
    }
```

and the EJS is

```
<li><h1><%=(value.direction + "put").toUpperCase()%> : <%=value.argument%></h1></li>
```

my problem is the 'value.isMultipleInput' is undefined in the EJS, even if the value is available.

How do I do?

Comment: I think the EJS snippet is missing the call to `value.isMultipleInput`. Could you add that? Also, it might be helpful to add information on how you load the template and its context.

Answer (score 0):

Since metaworks3 uses dwr and it will recognizes its property name from setter/getters. So, in the EJS, the property name 'isMultipleInput' should be 'multipleInput' instead.

use `value.multipleInput` rather old one.